# 4bit number to seven segment

Tags: verilog, seven-segment-display

I have a 4 bit output number as output. How can it be seen on seven segment display as hexadecimal number? I'm new and mentioning verilog. So, I have a four bit binary number and want to display it as hexadecimal. Ex. 1010(10) as A

case example:

```
wire [3:0] num;
case (num)
  4'b0000 : 1111110;
  4'b0001 : 0110000;
  4'b0010 : 1101101;
  4'b0011 : 1111001;
  so on
  .
  .
  4'b1111 : 1000111;
endcase
```

[image]

4 bit binary to seven segment

```
#TABLE: x1,x2,x3,x4 => a,b,c,d,e,f,g

0000 => 1111110

0001 => 0110000

0010 => 1101101

0011 => 1111001

0100 => 0110011

0101 => 1011011

0110 => 1011111

0111 => 1110000

1000 => 1111111

1001 => 1111011

1010 => 1110111

1011 => 0011111

1100 => 1001110

1101 => 0111101

1110 => 1001111

1111 => 1000111
```

Comment: could you please be more specific? Do you want to say that you have a four bit binary number and you want me to display it as hexadecimal. Ex. 1111(15) as F

Comment: yes exactly mean @AbhishekSingh

Answer (score 1):

In Verilog, if you do not define the base type of a number, it will assume decimal. Ex: 10 is decimal ten not binary two. A case statement should be defined in a always block.

```
reg [6:0] led;
wire [3:0] num;
always @* begin
  case (num)
    4'b0000 : led = 7'b1111110;
    /* you fill in the rest */
    4'b1111 : led = 7'b1000111;
  endcase
end
```